# Creating collection of objects with sequential property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, object, collections

I'm creating a collection of custom sequential objects.

There are ten properties on these objects; nine of them will be identical. The tenth property is its position in the sequence.

What's the best way to create these? I was thinking of writing a loop, and I can do that, but I was wondering if there's a better and/or more efficient way of doing this?

My environment is ASP.NET 4.0/VB.NET. I also work in C#, so I can translate a sample in C#...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
' Create 5 widgets:
Dim widgets = Enumerable.Range(0, 5) _
    .Select(Function(index) _
        New Widget With
        {
            .Property1 = 1,
                ...
            .Property9 = 9,
            .Position = index
        }) _
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, probably exactly what I need - thanks!